# Searching using a variable for date parameters in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am attempting to search using a variable to set a certain date as a parameter,

what i am trying to do is:

```
select cars,trucks 
from vehicles 
WHERE ACCESS TIME BETWEEN VARIABLE1 and VARIABLE2
```

.....

So i want to declare variable 1 and variable 2 to be a certain date in the format....
01/JaN/2008 01:09:08.

these variables would change so i am using variables so i can set the variables without having to access the query every time.

i have never done this, and its a small exercise

anyone can help me and lead me in the right way

Comment: What is the datatype of access time?

Comment: You want to avoid the inclusive upper-bound of [`BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (The blog post covers SQL Server, but this applies to all RDBMSs, and all continuous-range types).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a PL/SQL procedure/function !? - Just define the variables like:

```
DECLARE
   l_today_date        DATE := SYSDATE;
   l_today_timestamp   TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;
   l_today_timetzone   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE := SYSTIMESTAMP;
   l_interval1         INTERVAL YEAR (4) TO MONTH := '2011-11';
   l_interval2         INTERVAL DAY (2) TO SECOND := '15 00:30:44';
BEGIN
   null;
END;
```

You can also define it with: `to_date('2010-02-02','YYYY-MM-DD')`